# Python Mock: Stub method only for set parameters

Tags: python, mocking, mockito

Python `mockito` lets you stub methods when called with certain parameters.

E.g.

```
from mockito import when

# No wonder that modules have to be imported first
import os.path

# Stub calls
when(os.path).exists("/some/dir").thenReturn(True)
when(os.path).exists("\some]dir").thenRaise(AssertionError("Invalid directory name"))

# Use stubs
assert os.path.exists("/some/dir")
assert os.path.exists("\some]dir") # raises AssertionError: Invalid directory name
```

https://code.google.com/p/mockito-python/wiki/Stubbing#Modules

What's the equivalent with the python `mock` library?

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock